# Slow smtp-server at GoDaddy for VPS - alternatives?

Tags: smtp, godaddy

A client runs a VPS at GoDaddy, and they tell us to use k2smtpout.secureserver.net for our web-apps.

But it usually takes 10-15 minutes to send an email, which is totally unacceptable.

Is anybody using other options from GoDaddy hosting - what are my options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GoDaddy support gave me another smtp-server to use: p3smtpout.secureserver.net

And that works much faster, email is just seconds underway.

Answer (score 2):

Before you go shopping around are you positive that the delay is due to the smtp server they are using for outbound email?  Grey Listing is pretty popular these days and it also results in delays in the delivery of email.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked through the email headers to see where the delay is happening? Check through the "Recieved:" lines and see if any one of the servers is holding onto the message for longer than it should.